# Redis Session State Provider reset connection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, caching, redis

We are using RedisSessionStateProvider and have encountered an issue with changing the connection string while the service is ruining.

The connection string we provide lists the nodes that RedisSessionStateProvider is supposed to talk to. In the event that something goes wrong with the cluster, we would like to force RedisSessionStateProvider to get a new connection string with new nodes. I can't find any way to force this to happen. As far as I can tell, RedisSessionStateProvider uses static ProviderConfiguration and never changes it after service start so the only way for our service to recover is to restart the whole thing.

Is there a way around this? I would like for the service to be able to recover on its own without manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further testing, the bellow code doesn't actually do what I need.

So unfortunately, there is no built in way to solve the problem, but it can be done with reflection

```
FieldInfo configProperty = typeof(RedisSessionStateProvider).GetField("configuration", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
object config = configProperty.GetValue(null);
PropertyInfo connectionStringProperty = config.GetType().GetProperty("ConnectionString");
connectionStringProperty.SetValue(config, "new value");
```